# Mysqli Multi Query Or A better Alternative

Tags: php, mysql

I have an appointment database and I can successfully print the data. What I want to do now is limit the appointments that are shown to the result from query 1.

I currently get two errors the first one is unexpected query and the other error is Fatal error: Function name must be a string. How would i rewite it so that both queries work? or an alternative better way to get this working

```
    <?php
    //MySqli Databse Connection
        require "id.php";
        require "calendarconnect.php";

    //MySqli Select Query 1
    $lep = $mysqli->query("SELECT lep FROM appointments WHERE ID = $contactid");
    $line = mysqli_fetch_array($query1, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    //MySqli Select Query 2
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT ID, appointment, nature, doctorname, lep FROM appointments WHERE lep = $line ORDER BY appointment");

    print '<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3" border="1" class="sortable">';
    print '<tr><th>Date/Time</th><th>Nature</th><th>Doctor Name</th><th>Actions</th></tr>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        print '<tr>';
        print "<td>" . date('m-d-y g:i A', strtotime($row['appointment'])) . "</td>";
        print '<td>'.$row["nature"].'</td>';
        print '<td>'.$row["doctorname"].'</td>';
        print "<td><a href=\"edit.php&cd=" . $row['ID'] . "\">Edit&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a>";
print "<a href=\"appointmentdelete.php?id=" . $row['ID'] . "\"onclick=
      \"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";
        print '</tr>';
    }  
    print '</table>';

    require "freeclose.php";
?>
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a `JOIN` to make this one query?

Answer (score 1):

Its not necessary to do it with 2 Querys. So you not must transfer the result from Query 1 to the client to put in in the second.

Try this:

```
  SELECT b.ID, b.appointment, b.nature, b.doctorname, b.lep  
    FROM appointments a  
    LEFT JOIN appointments b ON b.lep = a.lep 
    WHERE a.ID = $contactid
    ORDER BY b.appointment;
```

Comment: @bernd-fuffen I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'b' (T_STRING)

Comment: sorry my mistake. it must be: 

SELECT b.ID, b.appointment, b.nature, b.doctorname, b.lep  
FROM appointments a WHERE a.ID = $contactid 
LEFT JOIN appointments b ON b.lep = a.lep 
ORDER BY b.appointment;

Comment: @bernd-fuffen I still get the same error. I want to return all appointments who have the same lep as the first one I am returning. Every appointment has a different ID in the database.

Comment: ohh ohh, its to late for me.if have copied the WHERE before the LEFT JOIN. What a Mistake, I have edit my first answer. Sorry again

Comment: @MarquiseR That's a PHP parse error. Bernd has given you SQL code. It's up to you to put it in valid PHP.